# add database Tablenames to the JList in java

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlist

```
// Declare JList
private JList jlstTab, jlstCol;
.
.
.
DefaultListModel dlmTables = new DefaultListModel();
DefaultListModel dlmCol = new DefaultListModel();

        // Instantiate 
        dlmTables.addElement("kl");
        jlstTab= new JList(dlmTables);
     jlstTab.setSelectedIndex(0);
        jlstTab.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

.
.
.
.

//Connect to the database
public static void main(String args[])
    {
   DBToolSwing cs = new DBToolSwing("DB Tool Swing");
   try


                  DBAccessObject dbAccess1 = new DBAccessObject("jdbc:odbc:JavaClassDSN");
          DBAccessObject dbAccess2 = new DBAccessObject();
                  ResultSet rsTables = dbAccess1.getDatabaseTableNames();
          while (rsTables.next())
          System.out.println(rsTables.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
```

I need to get the table names from the database, the output shouldn't be printed on the screen, instead I need the output added to the JlstTab 
so dlmTables.addElement("TABLE_NAME");
Please if someone can help I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both snippet is working for you. I mean you are able to print the table names on the console, and you are also able to show some fixed value in your JList. So, why not, instead of `System.out.println(rsTables.getString("TABLE_NAME"))` use `dlmTables.addElement(rsTables.getString("TABLE_NAME"))`. Where is the problem?